# How to make a property of an enum type when I am not using POCO's but EF generated model classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a table called `DynamicControl`. It has a property named `ControlType`, which is of `nvarchar(255)` in the SQL Server 2008 database.

In the code, I want the property value to be a string but its string value must come from the string representation of an enum, like so:

```
public enum ControlType
{
    TextBox,
    TextArea,
    Password,
    RadioButton,
    Checkbox,
    DropDownList,
    MultiSelectList,
    DatePicker,
    TimePicker,
    DateTimePicker
}
```

How do I do that?

**Update**
I forgot to add an important bit of information, without providing which, this might sound like a stupid question. The bit is: I am not using POCO's. I am constrained by legacy to use the Entity Framework generated model classes. If I were writing POCO's, I'd simply have changed the data type to the enum. However since I am using the generated model, doing that will cause a difference between the EDMX mark-up and the model classes.

**Update** My question is, *how do I tell Entity Framework to generate the right mark-up in the EDMX so that the said property is of type ControlType enum instead of string or Int32?*

Therefore, my question is **not** *how to convert an enum into a string and vice-versa*.

Comment: You do unerstand that any property of this enumeration type would be an integer not a string right?

Comment: Yes, I do. If I were writing POCO's, I'd write a property setter to do the translation. I am using the Entity Framework generated classes, though.

Comment: Its still not clear the reason Charles's suggestion wouldn't work which is basically Bartdude's suggestion only with more detail.  Update your question with the relevant information you just shared.

Comment: These suggestions would work. But every time I updated my model, the hand-written property would be over-written by the model generated classes. I need a way to tell the EDMX generator that I want a certain property to be of type enum, so that it spits out the right mark-up in the EDMX.

Comment: That just tells me that a hand written peropety shouldn't be used.  An enumeration property seems strange to use if its actually going to be called `ControlType`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define your property to be of the type of your enum (ie : ControlType)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that for this little project, I am not using POCO's but the generated classes that the Entity Framework generates.

Answer (score 0):

Enum class in .Net framework has many Static member functions to help ypu. 
   Assuming that you fetch nvarchar value from DB into a string variable named dbCtrlType, then

```
 public ControlType ControlTypeEnum
 {
     get { return (ControlType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ControlType), dbCtrlType); }
     set { dbCtrlType = dbCtrlType.ToString(); }
 }
```

Comment: My apologies. I've just clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct then you need something similar with little fine-tuning

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum ControlDefaultClass
    {
        [Description("This is some string which you wanted to show")] MemberA,
        [Description("This is some other string which you wanted to show")] MemberB,
    }

    public class ConsoleApp
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetDescription(ControlDefaultClass.MemberA));  //This line will print - This is some string which you wanted to show
            Console.WriteLine(GetDescription(ControlDefaultClass.MemberB));//This line will print - This is some other string which you wanted to show
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
        {
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes =
                (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I know how to get a string representation of an enum and vice versa. My question is "how do I tell Entity Framework that I want it to generate the model in such a way that it creates the property of type enum instead of a primitive."